# send HTML code in URL to doGet() function to send Emails

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, url, html-email

**How can I send HTML code in URL to doGet(e) function?**

our team sends emails, but all emails go from one account on the owner's behalf. I collect some data from Google Sheets, make its HTML, paste this HTML code in a temporary range and call the doGet function which picks this code and sends the email. This doGet() function is published as web app by the account owner so emails are sent on his behalf.

```
var sent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlOfwebApp + "?recipient=" + recipients + "&urlOfGSheet=" + urlssEmail+"&shtName="+shtName);
```

Then doGet function picks the HTML from Google Sheet cell:

```
function doGet(e){
var htmlTable = mySheet.getRange('A1').getValue();//This has HTML code pasted in it
MailApp.sendEmail(e.parameter.recipient, subject,'', { htmlBody: htmlTable});
}
```

However, this is inefficient as multiple emails are to be sent and it's slow plus doesn't seem a good code. I want my HTML to transfer directly to doGet() function. *I tried but it gives my a lot of errors cz of HTML syntax like ", < br> etc. So, how do I send it efficiently?*

Later on, I also want to email Sheets/tabs as attachments but that would be easier this way as I'm currently doing I guess.

Comment: You can use backticks to add html code like this. You can use multiple lines too ``var htmlTable = `<h1>Title</h1>` ``

Comment: I have 3 questions. 1. Can I ask you about the setting of your deployed Web Apps? 2. About `How can I send HTML code in URL to doGet(e) function?`, how much size of your HTML is? 3. What is the relationship between your question and `Later on, I also want to email Sheets/tabs as attachments but that would be easier this way as I'm currently doing I guess.`?

Comment: @machan I tried using backslash to escape, but that didn't help. I'd try your suggestion as well.

Comment: @Tanaike 1) What settings would affect it? It's deployed as web app, to be run by a specific email account and accessible by anyone. 2) size is not much, it's just a greetings message and a table of a few (avg. 20) lines for placing orders that's it. 3) That is something like more advanced or a next step to it but not required as of now. I'm only concerned with main question of sending HTML to doget() function.

Comment: @machan I tried using backticks: Exception: Invalid argument: https://script.google.com/macros/s/**ID here**/exec?recipient=***emailhere***&urlssEmail=**urlofsheet**&shtName=Credentials&backHTML=\`<p%20style%20=%20"font-family:Poppins;<br>Hey,</p><table%20cellspacing="0";font-style:normal;"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Item</th><th>Qty</th><th>Price</th></tr><tr><td style="text-align:center;">5</td><td%20style="text-align:left;background-color:#e7f9ef">**name**</td><td%20style="text-align:center;">5</td><td>%20%20%20%20</td></tr></table><bThanks,\`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Well encodeURLcomponent function solves the issue but it return too long URL and now I get URL limit exceeded error. @Tanaike I'm just trying to send HTML string in a URL to a different script, that's all.